# Project R - Barplot of occurrences of levels

Tags: r, plot

I am struggling with some plots. I have a really big data.frame with some entries. To get an overview I will work with some test data.

Let's assume the following data:

```
Sender <- c("ARD", "ZDF", "ARD", "ARD", "ZDF", "ZDF", "ARD")
Akz <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
NAkz <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
data <- data.frame(Sender, Akz, NAkz)
```

I want to get a (stacked) barplot group by the column "Person". So for each person I want to illustrate the occurrences of the columns "A" and "NA". Means one bar represents the column "A" with 3 "0"s and 4 "1"s and next to this bar I want the column "NA" with 4 "0"s and 3 "1"s. Would be great if there is a possibility to have a legend and the total amount of each level.

Thanks and all the best
Peter

PS: Found a pictures which illustrates a cool barplot. But I am not able to create this since the work with integers and total amounts[image]

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  Where is 'Sender', Akzept', NAkzept defined?

Comment: have a look at ggplot2

Comment: @akrun See the code above. I created the data.frame with the levels. And the illustrated barplot is an example.

Comment: @User632716 Did this already... To work with ggplot you have rearrange the data. Sorry, not so easy for me

Comment: Your example is not consistent. `Sender` is not defined. You can't name a vector `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a bit messed up, I trust this is what you wanted to post:

data:

```
Person <- c("ARD", "ZDF", "ARD", "ARD", "ZDF", "ZDF", "ARD")
Akzept <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
NAkzept <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
df <- data.frame(Person, Akzept, NAkzept)
```

The key to plotting in ggplot2 is to arrange the data in long format achieved by the function `gather`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(var, val, Akzept:NAkzept) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = interaction(var, Person), fill = val))
```

[image]

or perhaps:

```
  df %>%
    gather(var, val, Akzept:NAkzept) %>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_bar(aes(x = Person, fill = val))+
    facet_wrap(~var)
```

[image]

with text:

```
  df %>%
    gather(var, val, Akzept:NAkzept) %>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_bar(aes(x = Person, fill = val))+
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label =  ..count.. , x = Person, group = val),  position = "stack", vjust = 2, hjust = 0.5)+
    facet_wrap(~var)
```

[image]

Comment: `tidyverse` loads `ggplot2` automatically, so you don't have to explicit load it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right: My example with messed up. Fixed it. But I don't understand your code and your plot. If you look at "ARD": We have three 0s and four 1s. So in total 7. When you look at your plot you will see 8. I want to illustrate the "0" and "1" in one bar for each column "Akzept" and "N Akzept". So I want two bars for Person "ARD" (and two for "ZDF").

Comment: @Peter is the edit more in line with your expected output?

Comment: @missuse The last one is perfect. Is there any possibility to show the occurrences? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Peter added graph with text annotation, colors are customizable  however these are default ggplot colors, perhaps the order is reversed?

Comment: @missuse Yeah, That's it! Thanks a lot